# How To Get uvec4 Output from a GLSL Program

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to write a GLSL shader with uvec4 output but its not working.

This simple program results in black, when I expect white...

Do I need to do something on the c++ side to receive the uvec4 data?

```
smooth out uvec4 Result;

void main(void)
{
   Result = uvec4(255, 255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Try this: Result = uvec4(4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uvec4` is an unsigned integer type. You can only write unsigned integer values to a texture that *also* has an unsigned integer [texture format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format). **Warning**: do not confuse normalized texture formats with integer formats. `GL_RGBA8` is *not* an unsigned integer texture format. It is an unsigned normalized texture format. If you want to write actual integers, then you should write `GL_RGBA8UI`.

However, if I may read your intentions, you probably expect `uvec4(255, 255, 255, 255)` to be white. You can't do that. If you want to render to the screen, you must use proper floating-point color values. These will be converted to the appropriate values for output. If the output image is `GL_RGBA8` in format, then float values on the range [0, 1] will be converted to [0, 255] for storage.

So you should be writing to a `vec4` and writing values on the [0, 1] range. Don't try to fight it; just accept it now and move on.

Comment: I'm intending to use it for non-image purposes, such as collision detection, picking, etc. The math for what I'm trying to implement is designed around integers. I was rendering to the screen for testing purposes. Are you saying I need to render to a texture with uint color values for this to work?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Your texture needs to have an integer image format.